# if statement with while function

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this code if there are data in sql it works fine but if there is no data i get an error in line 8 but it should stop after line 4-5 and go to that page somebody who can tell me What may be wrong?

```
<?php
include "../conf/pagebilleder.php";
$hugo = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if ($hugo < 0){
header("Location: ../index.php");
}
else {
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){ 
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `$hugo` will __never__ be `< 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't if be a equal to sign in if statement? Because if it is zero it should go to index?

```
if ($hugo <= 0){
header("Location: ../index.php");
}
```

Comment: thx, that was the error. are you able to tell me how to make header to work i get this error

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: Make sure the path of the header is correct. If index is on the same location as the webpage in which this code is, then just index.php should work. Else you need to specify the full path of the index file.

Comment: if ($hugo <= 0){
 ?>
    <script>
 top.location.href = "http://localhost/index.htm";
 </script>
    <?php
 }